# Terraform issue on macOs

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-docker

I started to learning terraform, I have installed terraform and docker desktop on my macbook.
I am following the [quick start tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws-get-started/install-cli#quick-start-tutorial) and got below error.

**ERROR**

```
╷
│ Error: Error pinging Docker server: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker"],
│   on main.tf line 10, in provider "docker":
│   10: provider "docker" {}
│
```

**Docker status**

```
    ❯ docker --version
    Docker version 20.10.20, build 9fdeb9c
    ❯ docker ps
    CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                NAMES
    f6633f3b801e   docker/getting-started   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   flamboyant_volhard
```

**main.tf**

```yaml
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        docker = {
          source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
          version = "~> 2.13.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "docker" {}
    
    resource "docker_image" "nginx" {
      name         = "nginx:latest"
      keep_locally = false
    }
    
    resource "docker_container" "nginx" {
      image = docker_image.nginx.latest
      name  = "tutorial"
      ports {
        internal = 80
        external = 8000
      }
    }
```

Issue has been resolved, solution available [in this link](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6531)

Comment: There is no error in the question and the link is broken. Please post the error as text.

Comment: Please add all the relevant code blocks. The one containing the provider as well as the docker_container resource.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the provider documentation [1] (as the error describes as well), you need to switch to the following:

```
terraform {
   required_providers {
     docker = {
       source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
       version = "~> 2.22.0"
      }
    }
}
    
provider "docker" {}

resource "docker_container" "nginx" {
  image = docker_image.nginx.image_id
  name  = "tutorial"
  ports {
    internal = 80
    external = 8000
  }
}

resource "docker_image" "nginx" {
  name         = "nginx:latest"
  keep_locally = false
}
```

The example from the tutorial is using a very old version of Docker provider. When you make these changes, make sure to run `terraform init -upgrade` prior to running `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs/resources/container#example-usage

Comment: Warning has been resolved. But still get error `Error: Error pinging Docker server: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: =)

❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
❯ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.20, build 9fdeb9c

Comment: ❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                NAMES
f6633f3b801e   docker/getting-started   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   flamboyant_volhard

Comment: Please add the provider block to the question.

Comment: Something else?

Comment: not possible to add code.

Comment: code available in here 
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws-get-started/install-cli#quick-start-tutorial

Comment: Issue has been resolved, solution available in this link
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6531

Comment: Just in case issue have related to docker not to the main.tf syntaxis. How ever main,tf could not apply while docker issue was not resolved. and regarding syntax, it have been just warning.